# PHP: List all includes

Tags: php

I have a large complex PHP project made up of many PHP files.

Is there some function I can call in my code that will return a list of all included files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`get_included_files` or `get_required_files` (alias of `get_included_files`)

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-required-files.php (Alias of `get_included_files`)

```
<?php
// This file is abc.php

include 'test1.php';
include_once 'test2.php';
require 'test3.php';
require_once 'test4.php';

$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
?>

-----
The above example will output:

abc.php
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
test4.php
```

Comment: You can just use `var_dump(get_included_files())` instead of using a foreach loop. The function returns an array.

Comment: This has helped me again, over 13 years after I asked the question 

Answer (score 2):

```
register_shutdown_function(
    function() {
        your_logger(get_included_files());
    }
);
```

get_included_files will be called at the end of script execution, so u`ll get full list of included files

Comment: While this may be the answer, it is recommended to include documentation and/or explanation in your answer.

Comment: This is not true, the function will only return the included files, at the order where the function has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/get_included_files)