# List all loaded files in PHP

Tags: php

There is no way on denying that PHP is based on includes. Even PSR4 is responsible for including files from folders so, so far away.

Sometimes it become very difficult to debug code, mainly on third party code, don't matter how good it was written.

With `PHP` being so dynamic in function calling it is very easy to get lost. And the URL don't help much in software like MOODLE.

Is there a way to tell PHP to error_log every file that was loaded in a request? So I can know the files i need to debug.

I don't think using the [PHP magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) will help much.

Comment: You mean [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: List all includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307376/php-list-all-includes)

Comment: Have you considered NEtBeans or similiar with XDEBUG

Comment: look at an exception backtrace

Comment: This is where understanding the framework used is good, e.g. if you know how to code Magento 2 you know how to break up the URL to find the file. There are also tools, Riggs has mentioned XDEBUG which is a godsend, I personally use PHPStorm for my doings and that's really good at getting root declaration of functions etc.

Comment: Usually looking at the stack trace is enough to determine the files you need to check without needing to check all included files. The stack trace is usually available in logs when an unhandled exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_included_files()`

This function returns all required and included file names as array.